# Where is the first Boeing 747-8 ever built stored at today?

Tags: boeing-747

I have tried many different ways to try to find where it is stored, but have had no luck.

Comment: Looks like it's currently 'stored' on the ramp at Luxembourg International Airport, after landing there on its most recent flight in from Calgary yesterday evening. As aeroalias said, it's in cargo service for Cargolux Airlines. If you want to see where it is at any given time, you can just [look up the tail number on flightaware](http://flightaware.com/live/flight/LXVCA) or some similar website. The tail number of this particular aircraft is currently LX-VCA.

Answer (score 6):

The first 747-8 built was not a protype, but a production unit. The first delivered aircraft in both the versions (747-8i Intercontinenal and 747-8F Freighter) are in service, the Passenger version with Lufthansa and the cargo version with Cargolux.

The first 747-8 customer was Cargolux for the 747-8F version.

The first 747 ever built, 747 RA001 'City of Everett' is in Museum of Flight in Seattle.

Comment: References would be useful if possible